# AWS launch a new instance: how to specify a specific region such as us-west-1c?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, region

AWS launch a new instance: how to specify a specific region?

For example, We have a volume in `us-west-1c`. Need to launch a new instance in the same region to attach the volume. Launching an instance in `us-west-1d` will not work.

But in the instance launch page, there is no place to specify the region `us-west-1c`. From the top-right corner in the console page, only select region such as us-west-1 and could not select us-west-1c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`us-west-1c` is an [availability zone](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Concepts.RegionsAndAvailabilityZones.html#Concepts.RegionsAndAvailabilityZones.AvailabilityZones) [AZ], NOT a [region](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Concepts.RegionsAndAvailabilityZones.html#Concepts.RegionsAndAvailabilityZones.Regions). Each region is composed of 3+ AZs.

For an EC2 instance, AZ is chosen when you choose a [subnet](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/configure-subnets.html) on instance creation page. If you do not specify subnet, a random subnet is going to be used, and thus a random AZ.